# How to calculate a negative number in assembly

Tags: assembly

I'm a newbie in assembly and I have a question about how to represent negative numbers
I have three DWORDS variable, let say:

```
result DWORD 0
i DWORD 3
j DWORD 5
```

and I want to calculate this formula: result = i - j + 8
but, when i do the i-j, the result will be a very high number because of the sign
so how do I make the result ok in the end?

Comment: What do you mean by "OK"?  The "high number" as you call it would be the appropriate result.

Comment: Brian is right, your high number is actually just a signed version of the result. You are probably just displaying the unsigned version if you think it's "very high"

Answer (score 11, accepted):

For 32 bit DWORD the integer range is from –2147483648 to 2147483647 or in hex -0x80000000 to 0x7FFFFFFF.

So the number -1 is present like 0xFFFFFFFF. (Like counter underflow)

If the high (31) bit is set then the number is negative. To make positive number from negative (negation) you must make compement of number and add 1.

**Example:**

```
    0xFFFFFFFE   //-2
xor 0xFFFFFFFF   //binary complement 
---------------
    0x00000001   //result of complement
+   0x00000001   //add 1
---------------
    0x00000002   //Result of negation is 2
```

Comment: This method is useful mentally, if you don't want to tell your debugger to print it as signed decimal like GDB `p (int)$eax`.  If you're writing a program to to it, subtract from 0, like x86 `neg eax`.  Or ARM `rsb r2, r1, #0` (reverse-subtract, does r2 = 0-r1).

Answer (score 0):

Notice:

If you compare two integers you use other jump command than comparing absolute numbers:

Comparing absolute numbers:

```
jg (jump if greater)
jl (jump if less)
```

Comparing integers (which can be negative or positive):

```
ja (jump if greater)
jb (jump if less)
```

Answer (score 0):

Negative numbers are represented in Two's Complement in assembly. In order to obtain Two's Complement of a number you have two options:

- to complement all it's bits and add one.
- to complement all it's bits until the last 1