# How to convert a positive number to negative in assembly

Tags: assembly, x86

I want to convert a positive number to negative in assembly,
I need a code sample

The input is in hex sdword

Thanks

Comment: you need to specify a processor.  every processor uses a different set of operations.

Comment: Which assembly language?

Comment: Use the NEG instruction.  "hex sdword" doesn't mean anything, hex is for humans.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to calculate a negative number in assembly](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4259949/how-to-calculate-a-negative-number-in-assembly)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Well, there are two ways to do this, best would be to load the number into a register, then use the `NEG` instruction as Hans mention, ie: `NEG EAX` would negate eax. The other way would be `XOR EAX,EAX SUB EAX,EDX` where edx contains the number you want to negate

Comment: Instead of `XOR EAX,EAX`, why not just `MOV EAX, 0h`?

Comment: @user1720897: `XOR EAX,EAX` is a dependency breaking idiom (see the intel optimization guide), this means the CPU can use register renaming to speed things up. its also a smaller encoding, this helps with i-cache pressure and instruction fetch-and-decode. TBH, it makes no difference in this case, its just a habit of mine (but not a bad habit).

Answer (score 1):

You can take the two's complement of the number. I.e. Bitwise NOT followed by addition of one.

```
Data Segment
  num dw 00000010B
Data Ends

Code Segment
  Assume cs:code, ds:data

  Begin:
    mov ax, data
    mov ds, ax
    mov es, ax
    mov ax, num
    NOT ax
    add ax, 00000001B

  Exit:
    mov ax, 4c00h
    int 21h
Code Ends
End Begin
```

Comment: I want to convert a number that located in sdword in hexadecimal and not binary

Comment: That doesn't make a difference, you can use the same instruction for hex. Just replace 000000010B with 0x123 for example

Comment: @MadhurAhuja if the number is negative it will change his sign too? if not what operation I need to do, to change positive to negative, and not to change negative to positive, in conclusion: just to change to negative if it pos and if it neg.

Answer (score -3):

Here's an online resource which shows how to do this for 80x86 processor: http://webster.cs.ucr.edu/AoA/DOS/ch01/CH01-2.html

Comment: This link no longer works. Now you know why link-only answers are discouraged.