# converting a negative number to a positive number in Assembly x86

Tags: assembly, x86

Is there any method to turn a negative number in assembly into a positive number? i heard that there is a way using the Logical Instruction "NOT"

While examining other guides for **Assembly X86** i didn't found any guide for converting a negative number into positive one.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to convert a positive number to negative in assembly](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4534503/how-to-convert-a-positive-number-to-negative-in-assembly)

Comment: NEG and NOT are different. I think I found a good duplicate :)

Comment: I tried examine that thread but it was very unclear...

Comment: What is unclear? Just do a "NEG", one instruction, that's it.

Answer (score 5):

I suggest another answer:

```
NEG ax
```

which does exactly the same as

```
NOT ax
INC ax
```

See [WikiPedia's Two's complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement#Most_negative_number):

> With only one exception, starting with any number in two's-complement representation, if all the bits are flipped and 1 added, the two's-complement representation of the negative of that number is obtained. Positive 12 becomes negative 12, positive 5 becomes negative 5, zero becomes zero(+overflow), etc.

Answer (score 2):

I have found the answer.
simply by using the code:

```
NOT ax
inc ax
```

will give you the wanted resault