# MASM32 problems with imul when multiply two negative numbers

Tags: assembly, x86, masm32

I mooved to register al number -100, now in al stored 9C in hexademical, the same thing I did with register bl, so in bl stored 9C too.
And here is the problem, when I do:

```
imul ebx
```

I get 00005F10h in register eax, it's 24336 in decimal instead of 10000 that I was expected to get.
What am I doing wrong?
Here is the part of code where I do this multiplication:

```
mov eax, 0
mov ebx, 0
mov ecx, 0
mov al, [sbAval+esi]
mov bl, [sbAval+esi]

power:
imul ebx
cmp ecx, 2
je powerDone
inc ecx
jmp power
```

sbAval is SBYTE data type

Here I have 9C stored in eax and ebx
[registers before imul](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IJ5rt.png)

And here is registers after imul [registers after imul](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kqcbF.png)

Comment: I found out that if we convert 9C as not signed number to decimal it's 156 and if we multiply 156*156 it equals 24336, exactly what I get, but what should I do with that? How to multiply two negative numbers in masm32?

Comment: You need to sign-extend, try `movsx eax, byte ptr [sbAval+esi]` in place of `mov al, ...`, and likewise `movsx ebx, ...`

Comment: Yeah it did work, thanks a lot

Comment: Why are you using widening one-operand imul in the first place?  Are you actually using the high half in EDX?  Normally you'd do `imul eax, ebx` (or use any registers, like EDX for the copy, so you don't have to save/restore a call-preserved register like EBX).  Also, why load from memory twice?  Just `mov edx, eax` after doing one movsx load.  (If you didn't need to multiply repeatedly, you could have used `imul al` to square into AX.)

Comment: No, I'm not, I did like it was in our lab example. I didn't know that doing imul eax, ebx won't affect EDX. And with thing about memory I agree too. Thanks I will edit my code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`-100` in 32-bit is not `0x9c`, it's `0xffffff9c`. If you put `0x9c` in the registers (rather than the actual integer -100), then you have there 156. It may not surprise you that `156*156=24336`. This is a likely source of confusion.

Following your edit, it seems like you won't be able to do this naturally using an SBYTE, due to the nature of the instructions padding the shorter data type with 0s (and treating it as a positive number). Use `movsx` to retain the sign while moving the SBYTE to a register.

Comment: Yeaaahhh but if I try to mov SBYTE number exactly to register EAX, not to AL, I get this Error: error A2070: invalid instruction operands

Comment: @kstamax.  Right, so use `movsx eax, byte ptr [sbAval+esi]` to do sign-extending byte->dword load.  (Right now you're emulating movzx by zeroing the full register and then doing a plain `mov` to merge into the low byte).  Plain `mov` always requires its operands to be the same width.  And MASM stopped you from loading 4 bytes from an address involving `sbAval`, because it associated that symbol name with byte operand-size.  `mov eax, dword ptr [...]` would override the size and load 4 bytes, which isn't what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the two's-complement system, `0x9C` is negative when stored in a single byte, and positive when stored using two or more bytes.

This is because in a two's-complement system, the most significant bit (i.e. the left-most one) signifies the sign, and the `1` makes it negatives.

When you extend the space to 32 bits where the MSB is `0` - the number is "processed" as positive.

One possible solution is to store `100` in `AL` and `BL` (after clearing `EAX` and `EBX`, like you do in your code), and then negate `EAX` and `BAX`. E.g. `NEG EAX` ( [How to convert a positive number to negative in assembly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4534503/how-to-convert-a-positive-number-to-negative-in-assembly) )